# AngularUI modal - displaying on page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using AngularUI 0.8.0 (with bootstrap 2.3) and trying to get a simple modal box to display.

Using the code below, when I press Open, the template and controller load, the alert is displayed, db receives the promise from $modal.open, then the template is rendered on the bottom of the existing page - not opened in a modal dialog.

What would cause this? How do I troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- ConfirmPage.cshtml -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.openModal()">Open</button>
```

The controllers are:

```
<!-- ConfirmPageCtrl.coffee -->
class ConfirmPageCtrl
    constructor: (@$scope, @$modal) ->
        $scope.ctrl = @

    openModal: () =>
        alert 'Called modal.open'
        db = @$modal.open
            templateUrl: '/Home/ConfirmTpl'
            controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        db.result.then @modalOk, @modalCancel

    modalOk: () ->
        alert 'I am OK!'

    modalCancel: () ->
        alert 'I have been cancelled :-('

class ModalCtrl
    constructor: (@$scope, @$modalInstance) ->

    ok: () =>
        @$modalInstance.close()

    cancel: () =>
        @$modalInstance.dismiss()

app.controller 'ConfirmPageCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$modal', ConfirmPageCtrl]

app.controller 'ModalCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$modalInstance', ModalCtrl]
```

Comment: Writing this in coffeeScript certainly doesn't help but perhaps if you created a jsfiddle then we could help you

Comment: Can you paste the template code? AFAIK, you need to specify an ID in `templateUrl` and not the path...